# Loop infinito ao digitar um caractere

Tags: c++, loop, stream

Estou fazendo testes de erro em meu programa "Monkey Teste" e ele entra em *loop* infinito quando digito um caractere no teclado que não seja número.

```
int ActionGenerator() {

    bool Verify;
    int Action;
    Verify = true;

    while(Verify){
        cout << "\nSELECIONE UMA ACTION: " << endl;
        cout << "[1 = ActionX]\n[2 = ActionZ]" << endl;
        cin >> Action;

        if (Action == 1 || Action == 2){
            return Action;
            Verify = false;

        }else {
            cout << "\nACTION INVALIDA !" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que especificamente você está digitando? Por que considera que está em *loop*? Por que fica dando a mensagem "ACTION INVALIDA"? Bom, é isto que o código está mandando fazer, sempre que tiver algo inválido ele dá esta mensagem e pede de novo. Se você tem outra intenção, descreva ela na pergunta.

Comment: o usuário tem que escolher uma ação, e é apresentado para ele na tela 2 Escolhas, ou 1 ou 2 para ele digitar, e depois retorna para meu main o resultado digitado pelo usuário, neste caso eu estou filtrando erros caso o usuário digite algo errado, vamos supor que ele digite acidentalmente uma letra, o código tem que filtrar este erro, que não é o que esta acontecendo...  preciso filtrar caso ele digite uma string

Comment: Acho que entendi, vou responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ActionGenerator() {

    int opcao;
    char *CleanBuffer;


    do{
        cout << "\nSELECIONE UMA ACTION: " << endl;
        cout << "[1 = ActionX]\n[2 = ActionZ]" << endl;
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        scanf("%c", &CleanBuffer);

        if (opcao = 1) {
            return opcao;


        }else if(opcao = 2){

            return opcao;

        }

        else {
            cout << "\nACTION INVALIDA !" << endl;
        }

    }while(opcao != 3)


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você pode fazer do jeito que você quiser mas eu não faria desta forma. Primeiro porque usa um recursos que não é mais recomendado pelo C++ e segundo porque ele valida o dado o suficiente. Erros do usuário passarão batido.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz um outro teste e o código original que postei não funciona em qualquer situação. Fiz um outro que é mais complicado, mas funciona. Ele pega uma *string* e tenta convertê-la para `int`. Se falhar é o mesmo que se o número seja inválido. Antes funciona quando havia um erro específico, agora trata qualquer entrada inválida. E como é feito através de função especializada, não precisa se preocupar com o estado do *stream* padrão.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int ActionGenerator() {
    int Action;
    string Input = "";
    while(true) {
        cout << endl << "SELECIONE UMA ACTION: " << endl;
        cout << "[1 = ActionX]" << endl << "[2 = ActionZ]" << endl;
        getline(cin, Input);
        stringstream myStream(Input);
         if ((myStream >> Action) && (Action == 1 || Action == 2)){
            return Action;
        } else {
            cout << endl << "ACTION INVALIDA !" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << ActionGenerator() << endl << "ok" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jR1xDW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uvzdtstg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/GetChars.cpp).

Note que fiz um teste com uma *string* mais que um caractere. Isto falhava no código anterior.

---

O código está difícil de entender porque não está mal indentado. Pode parecer bobagem mas isto faz uma diferença enorme para entender o código.

Tem parte que nunca será executada. E de fato não existe lógica para sair do *loop* a não ser que digite 1 ou 2. E nestes casos encerra-se a execução da função.

Mas o problema mesmo é que você não está liberando o estado do *stream*. Quando ocorre um erro uma *flag* de erro é *setada* para você saber que houve um problema quando tentou pegar um valor válido. Quando você digita algo que não pode ser convertido no tipo esperado, no caso um `int`, além do número ser convertido para 0, está *flag* fica *setada* e só se você explicitamente limpar isto é que poderá voltar trabalhar com o *stream*. Se a *flag* estiver *setada* o *stream* não funciona.

Outro problema ocorre que o dado digitado ainda fica no *buffer* e você precisa ignorar o que está nele.

Ou seja, o *stream* guarda estado e você tem que resolver isto.

Aproveitei e fiz uma melhoria para este caso:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ActionGenerator() {
    int Action;
    while(true) {
        cout << endl << "SELECIONE UMA ACTION: " << endl;
        cout << "[1 = ActionX]" << endl << "[2 = ActionZ]" << endl;
        cin >> Action;
        if (Action == 1 || Action == 2){
            return Action;
        } else {
            cout << endl << "ACTION INVALIDA !" << endl;
            cin.clear(); //Limpa a flag de erro quando há falha no parse do valor entrado
            cin.ignore(); //Limpa o buffer
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << ActionGenerator() << endl << "ok" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/K9EhtD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gebrzbmh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/GetChars2.cpp).

Tem outras maneira de tratar isto mas acho que para o exemplo simples que você deu não tem porque fazer nada mais complexo que isto.

Note que eu simplifiquei o *loop* também. Não havia razão para existir aquele controle neste caso.

Comment: c.clear();  cin.ignore(); resolveu, show de bola obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

O comando `cin>>` não trata entradas inválidas. `Action` é um inteiro, se alguém digitar uma string, gera um exceção não tratada, que acaba gerando o loop infinito. Você tem que gerar um código para tratar essa exceção. Você tem que capturar uma entrada do tipo array de caracteres (`char[]`), convertê-la para números, com tratamento de exceção para entradas inválidas, tipo:

```
if ( char[0] != '1' )
    ThrowException(); //Seu método para tratar e exceção
else
    number += 1 * (decimalPlace ); // primeira casa decimal neste caso.
```

Observação: `verify = false` depois de `return Action` nunca vai ser executado.

Comment: Notadamente o trecho de código descrito não é funcional. Mas serve para dar uma idéia do que pode ser feito. De fato, para a questão em contexto é um tanto complexa, mas é um ótimo exercício para principiantes.